# Get a state name from abbreviation

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, abbreviation

I have an app in place that returns  states abbreviation if the state is clicked. I would like to put a user message in place in the app that would require the actual state name and not the abbreviation.

If I click New York state,  I have "NY" stored in a variable named `data.name`. How can I use this data to get the full name of a state based off of its abbreviation?

I was thinking of using

```
var getStateInfo = function (abbrev, stateName) {

}
```

but I am not sure what I would put inside the function. I am also aware that there's probably a better approach to this. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a javascript object as a dictionary:

```
var states = {"NY":"New York", "NJ":"New Jersey"};
```

and access them like this:

```
alert(states["NY"]);
```

so your function that returns the full state name would work like this:

```
var getStateFullName = function (stateAbbr) {
  return states[stateAbbr];
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're going the opposite way, from the full name to the abbreviation.

Comment: Currently, I cannot rank upvote this or mark this as an answer. I am not sure why. I am new to this though. Any idea?

Comment: @MikeManusama there is a short window after asking where you can't accept an answer but you should be able to click the check mark now to accept it. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I have typescript (could be easy modified to js) function. Convert us state's abbreviation to full name and vice versa

```
export default function convertUsStateAbbrAndName(input: string): string | null {
  const toAbbr = input.length !== 2;

  const states = [
    ['Alabama', 'AL'],
    ['Alaska', 'AK'],
    ['American Samoa', 'AS'],
    ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
    ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
    ['Armed Forces Americas', 'AA'],
    ['Armed Forces Europe', 'AE'],
    ['Armed Forces Pacific', 'AP'],
    ['California', 'CA'],
    ['Colorado', 'CO'],
    ['Connecticut', 'CT'],
    ['Delaware', 'DE'],
    ['District Of Columbia', 'DC'],
    ['Florida', 'FL'],
    ['Georgia', 'GA'],
    ['Guam', 'GU'],
    ['Hawaii', 'HI'],
    ['Idaho', 'ID'],
    ['Illinois', 'IL'],
    ['Indiana', 'IN'],
    ['Iowa', 'IA'],
    ['Kansas', 'KS'],
    ['Kentucky', 'KY'],
    ['Louisiana', 'LA'],
    ['Maine', 'ME'],
    ['Marshall Islands', 'MH'],
    ['Maryland', 'MD'],
    ['Massachusetts', 'MA'],
    ['Michigan', 'MI'],
    ['Minnesota', 'MN'],
    ['Mississippi', 'MS'],
    ['Missouri', 'MO'],
    ['Montana', 'MT'],
    ['Nebraska', 'NE'],
    ['Nevada', 'NV'],
    ['New Hampshire', 'NH'],
    ['New Jersey', 'NJ'],
    ['New Mexico', 'NM'],
    ['New York', 'NY'],
    ['North Carolina', 'NC'],
    ['North Dakota', 'ND'],
    ['Northern Mariana Islands', 'NP'],
    ['Ohio', 'OH'],
    ['Oklahoma', 'OK'],
    ['Oregon', 'OR'],
    ['Pennsylvania', 'PA'],
    ['Puerto Rico', 'PR'],
    ['Rhode Island', 'RI'],
    ['South Carolina', 'SC'],
    ['South Dakota', 'SD'],
    ['Tennessee', 'TN'],
    ['Texas', 'TX'],
    ['US Virgin Islands', 'VI'],
    ['Utah', 'UT'],
    ['Vermont', 'VT'],
    ['Virginia', 'VA'],
    ['Washington', 'WA'],
    ['West Virginia', 'WV'],
    ['Wisconsin', 'WI'],
    ['Wyoming', 'WY'],
  ];

  // So happy that Canada and the US have distinct abbreviations
  const provinces = [
    ['Alberta', 'AB'],
    ['British Columbia', 'BC'],
    ['Manitoba', 'MB'],
    ['New Brunswick', 'NB'],
    ['Newfoundland', 'NF'],
    ['Northwest Territory', 'NT'],
    ['Nova Scotia', 'NS'],
    ['Nunavut', 'NU'],
    ['Ontario', 'ON'],
    ['Prince Edward Island', 'PE'],
    ['Quebec', 'QC'],
    ['Saskatchewan', 'SK'],
    ['Yukon', 'YT'],
  ];

  const regions = states.concat(provinces);

  let i; // Reusable loop variable

  if (toAbbr) {
    input = input.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt: string) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
    for (i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
      if (regions[i][0] === input) {
        return regions[i][1];
      }
    }
  } else {
    input = input.toUpperCase();
    for (i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
      if (regions[i][1] === input) {
        return regions[i][0];
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Inital source - [github](https://gist.github.com/calebgrove/c285a9510948b633aa47)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a case statement? Have it check data.name, and return the appropriate case? Ex. Switch(data.name) Case 0 (data.name == "NY") return "New York"

Comment: Slow and verbose way to do it.

Comment: You are correct, but this is one way to accomplish it.

Comment: Would you actually recommend doing it this way (instead of using an object)? If not, why post it as an answer?

Comment: And if you're going to post this answer, show the correct `switch/case` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to include abbreviations for US territories/not-state jurisdictions as well, here is the complete list:

```ts
export const getJurisdictionAbbrev = (jurisdiction: string) =>
  ({
    Arizona: 'AZ',
    Armed_Forces_Americas: 'AA',
    'Armed_Forces_Europe,_Canada,_Africa_and_Middle_East': 'AE',
    Armed_Forces_Pacific: 'AP',
    Alabama: 'AL',
    Alaska: 'AK',
    American_Samoa: 'AS',
    Arkansas: 'AR',
    California: 'CA',
    Colorado: 'CO',
    Connecticut: 'CT',
    Delaware: 'DE',
    District_of_Columbia: 'DC',
    Florida: 'FL',
    Georgia: 'GA',
    Guam: 'GU',
    Hawaii: 'HI',
    Idaho: 'ID',
    Illinois: 'IL',
    Indiana: 'IN',
    Iowa: 'IA',
    Kansas: 'KS',
    Kentucky: 'KY',
    Louisiana: 'LA',
    Maine: 'ME',
    Marshall_Islands: 'MH',
    Maryland: 'MD',
    Massachusetts: 'MA',
    Michigan: 'MI',
    Micronesia: 'FM',
    Minnesota: 'MN',
    Mississippi: 'MS',
    Missouri: 'MO',
    Montana: 'MT',
    Nebraska: 'NE',
    Nevada: 'NV',
    New_Hampshire: 'NH',
    New_Jersey: 'NJ',
    New_Mexico: 'NM',
    New_York: 'NY',
    North_Carolina: 'NC',
    North_Dakota: 'ND',
    Northern_Mariana_Islands: 'MP',
    Ohio: 'OH',
    Oklahoma: 'OK',
    Oregon: 'OR',
    Palau: 'PW',
    Pennsylvania: 'PA',
    Puerto_Rico: 'PR',
    Rhode_Island: 'RI',
    South_Carolina: 'SC',
    South_Dakota: 'SD',
    Tennessee: 'TN',
    Texas: 'TX',
    Utah: 'UT',
    Vermont: 'VT',
    Virginia: 'VA',
    Virgin_Islands: 'VI',
    Washington: 'WA',
    West_Virginia: 'WV',
    Wisconsin: 'WI',
    Wyoming: 'WY',
  }[jurisdiction]);
```